# How to create dictionary in c# with two keys?

Tags: c#, dictionary

In C#, I want to have a data structure that maps (x,y) coordinates to (x,y). How can I do something like this?

I don't want to convert the x,y coordinate into a single value using a formula like `y*w+x`. Is there a way to have `dictionary<key,key,(value,value)>`.

If I put the key as Tuple, then its an object and Tuple(1,1) does not equal Tuple(1,1). So I don't think I can find keys in that sense.

Comment: Can't you just define (or use the pre-existing) `Point` as a structure that holds `(x, y)` and then use that in your `Dictionary<Point, Point>`?

Comment: @omega remember if you use the System.Drawing.Point then your points coordinates should be `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just define (or use the [pre-existing structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.point?view=netframework-4.8) from the `System.Drawing` namespace) `Point` as a structure that holds (x, y) and then use that in your `Dictionary<Point, Point>`?

Answer (score 6):

If you use `struct` rather than `class` the keys will be compared based on the **values** not based on the **reference**, because the structs are **value type**

```
public struct Point
{
   public int x;
   public int y;
   public Point(int x, int y)
   {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
 }
```

Then using this struct

```
var dic = new Dictionary<Point,Point>();
dic.Add(new Point(1,1), new Point(1,2));

var f = dic[new Point(1,1)];
Console.WriteLine(f.x); //Output will be 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Point,string>();
dict[new Point(1,3)] = "asd";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any kind of object for as a dictionary key, as long as you correctly override `GetHashCode()` for that type. This is what the dictionary will use to determine whether a specific key exists in it or not. Therefore you can create your own class and use that as a key.

Check this answer for more information: [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer because the other ones seem to map to 1 string, and you need to map to 2 strings.
You could try using Point to stores the x and y position and then create a dictionary of a Tuple.

```
var points = new Dictionary<Point,Tuple<string, string>>();
points[new Point(1,1)] = new Tuple<string, string>("2","2");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Point
{
    public string X {get; protected set;}
    public string Y {get; protected set;}
    public Point(string x, string y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public HashSet<string> GetSet()
    {
        HashSet<string> result = new HashSet<string>();
        result.Add(this.X);
        result.Add(this.Y);
        return result;
    }
}
```

CreateSetComparer allows the dictionary to use the values of the set

```
List<Point> pointSource = GetSet();
Dictionary<HashSet<string>, Point> points = new Dictionary<HashSet<string>, Point>(HashSet<string>.CreateSetComparer());

foreach(Point d in pointSource)
{
    points.Add(d.GetSet(), d);
}
```

And finding a point:

```
HashSet<string> key = new HashSet<string>();
key.Add("X");
key.Add("Y");
Point myPoint = points[key];
```

May this link is help full [HashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =  new Dictionary<string, int>();

dictionary.Add("cat", 2);
dictionary.Add("dog", 1);
dictionary.Add("llama", 0);
dictionary.Add("iguana", -1);


if (dictionary.ContainsKey("apple"))
{
    int value = dictionary["apple"];
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```